# How to weight features when doing text mining?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, feature-selection, text-mining, feature-weighting

I have a case where I'm doing text mining over a list of product titles. In particular I want to run a clustering algorithm. But I also have some information about those products that I think can add a lot of information like the category of the product (if the product is a car, a furniture, etc)

When doing the vectorization of the text data I get a big number of text features ~100.000 and I am pretty sure the category information contains much more information than one single text token so the question is what is a reasonable weight for the category information when fitting a model using both the text features and the category information.

Answer (score 1):

For obvious reasons we cannot determine the weight for you.

Because there is no mathematical *correct* weight.

It's entirely up to you to increase the weight of some features you believe to be more important.